Subsets of a dense subset in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$
Consider $\{0,1\}$ equiped with the discrete topology and let $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the product topology.
$Y = \{ \chi_A: A \subset \mathbb{R}, A \text{ is countable}\} $
I'm trying to show that every infinite subset $K \subset Y$ has an accumulation point in $Y$.
What i tried to do is the following:
Since $K$ is infinite, let $(\chi_{A_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $\chi_{A_n} \in K$ for all $n$. $\chi_{\bigcup A_n} \in Y$, i've been trying to show that $\chi_{\bigcup A_n} \in \overline{K}$, but i don't know if this is the way to prove the statement.

This approach is wrong. For example, you can have $K$ to be the set of indicator functions of singletons. Then $\chi_{\cup A_n}$ is the indicator function of a countably infinite set, which is not in the closure of $K$. (Instead, the only accumulation point of $K$ is the zero function.)

Can you point me in the right direction? Just need a hint.

I would use the sequential compactness of ${0, 1}^X$ for any countable $X$ - since all your $\chi_{A_n}$ can be effectively thought of as elements of ${0, 1}^{\cup A_n}$, you can then use the sequential compactness of the latter space to extract a convergent subsequence. (If you haven’t seen that, this can be done via a diagonalization argument.)

I get what your saying. How would i go about proving that ${0,1}^X$ is sequentially compact for any countable $X$? What reference would recommend me so i can check that somewhere else?
And by " all your $\chi_{A_n}$ can be effectively thought of as elements of ${0,1}^{\cup A_n}$",  is that we have an homeomorphism between both things right? We can simply think about $\chi_{A_n}$ as an element of ${0,1}^{\cup A_n}$ with some $0$'s as extra padding, right?

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Product_of_Sequentially_Compact_Spaces_is_Sequentially_Compact#google_vignette
Found this one, thanks!! If you want to, you can post an answer to the question, i will approve it.
